# replace special character from mongoDB data

Tags: mongodb

how to convert "[\"Swollen_##_##*1\",\"Active*##_##*3\"]" to ["Swollen*##_##*1","Active*##_##_3"] using mongoDB query

Comment: That first is a string, the second is an array of strings.  That might be possible with regular expressions, but would probably be simpler on the cline side with a JSON parser.

Comment: what is your MongoDB version & this is for updates right ?